# How to rotate MPMoviePlayerController in center?

Tags: iphone

I have the following code:

```
- (void)initAndStartTranslation:(NSURL *)movieURL
{
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
    [self.view addSubview: player.view];

    [player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];

    [player setInitialPlaybackTime: -1.0];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
}
```

Player is fullscreen and all is ok. But it rotates in (0,0) coordinate. I want to rotate it in center. How can i do it?

I've tried to set the anchor point, also i tried to set it's center:

```
[player.view setCenter:self.view.center];
```

But there was no changes :|.

Comment: Do you mean that it rotate fine. but it rotates in a way that you dont like? or it rotates and go out of screen?

Comment: @hasan it looks normally after rotate. But in rotate process in goes out of screen. Video rotates not in center, but in top-left corner.

Comment: I found the solution. I just start using MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just start using MPMoviePlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let try the following:

Go to your xib file. select your view.

In the right pane click on the tab that you set size on.

You will find a box with the word origin under it.

change the origin to the centre. Tell me the result.

Comment: Thank you, Hasan. I use storyboards, not xib. I found the solution and added it as comment to my question.